# d3 add text to SVG rect

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm beginner in d3.js and I want to add some text and rect inner a rect.

here is my code:

```
            if (!_svg) {
            _svg = d3.select("#col1").append("svg")
                    .attr("height", _height - 2)
                    .attr("width", _width - 2);
        }

        _svg.append("text").attr({
            id: "leftDomainName",
            x: d3.select("svg").attr("width") / 14,
            y: d3.select("svg").attr("height") / 2,
            class: "vertical-text"
        }).text("Business Development");

        var g = _svg.append("g").attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            return "translate(0,0)";
        }).attr("clip-path", "url(#body-clip)");


        var mainBox = g.append("rect").attr({
            id: "mainBox",
            x: d3.select("svg").attr("width") / 8,
            y: 3,
            width: _width - 60,
            height: _height / 3,
            fill: "#D7FFEC"
        });

        mainBox.append("text").text("sample!!!");
        mainBox.append("rect").attr({
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
            width: _width - 60,
            height: _height / 3,
            fill: "red"
        });
```

I want to add a text and rect svg inner mainBox. In chrome develper tools I can see their was added but there aren't in page

[image]

what is my wrong?
thank you

***I append g to mainBox and then append my element to that g but it didn't work***

```
            var innerG = mainBox.append("g");

        innerG.append("text").text("sample!!!");
        innerG.append("rect").attr({
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
            width: _width - 60,
            height: _height / 3,
            fill: "red"
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can't add `text` to `rect` elements in SVG. To achieve what you want, add a `g` element that contains both `text` and `rect`:

```
g.append("text").text("sample!!!");
```

instead of

```
mainBox.append("text").text("sample!!!");
```

Comment: you mean inside of mainBox? I did it but it didn't work. I add my  new code into qustion section

Comment: Ah, it looks like you've appended all of this to another `rect` element. That won't work for the same reason -- if you want to group elements, use a `g` element.

Comment: after your comment I grouped them,but it didn't work.please see bold and italic line in question section

Comment: Don't append to `mainBox`, append to `g`.